# background tileSprite vertical scrolling straight road in Phaser

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have googled about the implementation of straight road using Javascript.
http://codeincomplete.com/games/racer/v1-straight/

However, I would like to check if Phaser framework gives a nice way to implement the straight road vertical scrolling background?

Here is what I expected the background scrolling the same as this game
http://www.nickjr.com/paw-patrol/games/paw-pups-save-the-day/

Thanks you in advance for guiding and sorry for any mistakes in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting downvoted because there is no 'nice and clever' way to implement a whole game on any engine/platform. If you want to build something, software takes a ton of work. Don't expect things to be magically done for you. So a tutorial is about the best you can hope for, and if you google it there's a lot of results.

That being said, [here's a Phaser tutorial that's magically done for you](https://www.anexia-it.com/blog/en/introduction-to-the-phaser-framework/), but I wouldn't go so far as to call it nice and clever. GLHF!

Comment: Thanks you for telling. I got a lot of downvoted for this question :(

Comment: Don't let it get to you bro. These people don't know you personally, so the downvotes are only a reflection on your question (and oftentimes, your question's title). Be sure to ask narrow, succinct questions that could have a clear answer. Check out the guidelines for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, if you found this answer useful please accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: I accepted your guiding bro. Thanks you